# How to start google maps zoomed in at my location

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have followed the Hellomap Tutorial and works great, but what I want to do is when the app starts for it to zoom into my location.

Here is my code:`

```
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
 mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
 mapView.getController().setZoom(7);
 List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
 Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
 CustomOverlay itemizedoverlay = new CustomOverlay(drawable, this);
 GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(24.3567 * 1E6), (int)(31.4387 * 1E6));
 OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hello!", "Guess Where I am");
 itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
 mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: So what is your problem? Find your location or zoom to geopoint (you got your current location geopoint) ?

Comment: please be more specific in your question. Choose one: a) 'This code is supposed to zoom into my current location and doesn't' OR b) 'what code should I add to make stuff happen?' Otherwise people have to read through your code looking for an error even if there isn't one. Try to keep the amount of work answerers need to do to a minimum

Comment: I like to zoom into my geopoint so that you can see the marker. At the moment I have to scroll to the right to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want set a fixed zoom level centered on your location do like this:

```
MapController controller = mapView.getController();
controller.setCenter(point);
controller.setZoom(ZOOM_LEVEL); // Some nice constant zoom level.
```

Comment: I have tried that but I get an error under point in controler.setCentre(point);

Comment: Never mind, had the code in the wrong place! (Think i need to take a break from this) :-)